# Refreshing date time in a div

Tags: jquery, html, datetime, razor, refresh

I am trying to refresh a div which has loading records with jquery ajax call and datetime. I am unable to refresh datetime. How can I do that

### HMTL

```
 <div class="linkText" id="detailsRefreshCont" >
     @DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd"), @DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm") 
     <span class="linkText" id="refreshDetails">Refresh</span>
 </div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$('#refreshDetails').click(function () {
     loadDetailsData();
     $("#detailsRefreshCont").load(location.href + " #detailsRefreshCont > *");
});
```

Comment: What does loadDetailsData() do?

Comment: Its a ajax call to bind data to div. But I am fine with that function. Only issue is with date time. I added it just to show that I am also doing other operations on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

location.href  not returns page

use correctly .load() method

https://api.jquery.com/load/

```
 $("#detailsRefreshCont").load("datetime.html");
```

or:
HTML

```
 <div class="linkText" id="detailsRefreshCont" >
 <span id="datetime">
  @DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd"), @DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm")
  </span> 
 <span class="linkText" id="refreshDetails">Refresh</span>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 $('#refreshDetails').click(function () {
 loadDetailsData();
 var now = new Date(), date = now.getDate(), month =  now.getMonth(), weekday=new Array(7), namemonth = new Array(12),day = now.getDay(), hour = now.getHours(), minute = now.getMinutes();
namemonth[0]="January";
namemonth[1]="February";
namemonth[2]="March";
namemonth[3]="April";
namemonth[4]="May";
namemonth[5]="June";
namemonth[6]="July";
namemonth[7]="August";
namemonth[8]="September";
namemonth[9]="October";
namemonth[10]="November";
namemonth[11]="December";
day -= 1; 
weekday[0]="Monday";
weekday[1]="Tuesday";
weekday[2]="Wednesday";
weekday[3]="Thursday";
weekday[4]="Friday";
weekday[5]="Saturday";
weekday[6]="Sunday";
 $("#datetime").html(namemonth[month]+ " "+weekday[day]+ ", " + hour +":"+ minute);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#detailsRefreshCont > *` selector seems to bring only elements with tags, try wrapping the date with something like `<span>`:

```
<div class="linkText" id="detailsRefreshCont" >
     <span>@DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd"), @DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm")</span>
     <span class="linkText" id="refreshDetails">Refresh</span>
</div>
```